# Windows folder share permissions

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, ip-address, share

I suppose this is straightforward but can't get a solution for it. When i share a windows folder (server 2012) and set its permissions (share or ntfs) then if someone from the network writes "\\servername\folder" all permissions are applied, but if instead uses the ip address "\\192.168.1.x\folder" windows ignores the permissions and gives access to everyone.

I'm sure it's my mistake somewhere. If anyone have a clue, i'll be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your permission. Windows stick the the more restrictive's one, always.

Thus in your case if the user can write, he got no DENY for him.

If you added a group with a deny permission dont forget the group membership got refreshed for the user when he relog.

ps, check to make sure your servername match the IP too.

Comment: Thank you. The servername matches the IP address. That's really my question, how can they have apparently different permissions ?